# PlayN 2.0 - How to prevent Android from autoscaling images?

Tags: android, playn

I am using PlayN 2.0 and I need to prevent Android from autoscaling images based on DPI. From what I've learned it seems that I need to store the images in /res/drawable-nodpi. My question is: Does this mean that I need to store the images in /res/drawable-nodpi instead of /assets? If so, what would be the most elegant way to achieve this when using PlayN 2.0?

Note: I'm new to both PlayN and Android. The autoscaling doesn't happen on all devices I tested. Is it possible that I'm missing something and the autoscaling effect is caused by something else? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/playn/B-22qA0jSWs

Summary of the answer: The density based scaling is performed by PlayN, not by Android. Disabling the scaling can be done by overriding the scaleFactor() method of GameActivity.